# Rebol Email Pop Server error

Tags: rebol

I have tested pop successufully with some POP servers with Rebol but it doesn't work with my hosting server dreamhost (which works with Outlook I have tested http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Outlook_Express ):

```
>> read pop://test@reboltutorial.com:password@reboltutorial.com
** User Error: Server error: tcp -ERR AVG POP3 Proxy Server: Cannot connect to the mail server!
```

I'm using REBOL/View 2.7.6.3.1 14-Mar-2008

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.rebol.com/faq.html    specifically #026

If that doesn't help, then you should post a trace which helps with most network issues:

`trace/net on`

and then try opening the pop port.

Comment: This link will take you straight to the FAQ that Graham correctly referred you to - http://www.rebol.com/faq.html#026

Answer (score 2):

read p: open [
    scheme: 'pop
    host: "reboltutorial.com"
    user: "test@reboltutorial.com"
    pass: "password"
]
close p

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was due to the fact that the mail account was linked to a gmail account by my webhosting so they disconnected from it.